# Qt Creator создает некорректный слот

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Подскажите, как решить следующую проблему.

Делаю проект в **Qt Creator**, кидаю на форму *QListWidget*, перехожу к слоту **itemDoubleClicked**, в результате чего **Qt** генерирует метод, который сразу же считается ошибочным...

Компилятор говорит, что:

```
ошибка: 'QListWidgetItem' has not been declared
void on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem *item);
                                      ^
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что пишет если навести на слот? в .h есть `#include <QListWidget>` или `#include <QListWidgetItem>`?

Comment: Иногда нужно запустить qmake для проекта

Comment: Нет. Хм, я думал, что Qt делает такие элементарные вещи автоматически... Искал ошибку, когда она лежала на поверхности -_-